# Integrating CakePHP plugin with my Application

Tags: cakephp

I'm struggling with how to integrate a User plugin with my application data. I'm using CakePhp 2.1.

Scenario:  I have existing membership and club lists, where members can belong to multiple clubs and clubs have multiple members.  I've created all the MVC and CRUD for members and clubs and they work fine.  And the associations work fine.

I've installed a User management plugin, which allows people to register, confirm, reset their passwords etc.  All that works fine.

Where I'm stuck is matching the new "user" with the existing "member" profile information.

When a person creates a login userid, we ask for the membership number and their name so that we can link the new login id with the membership number.

This is where I get stuck.

I've extended the plugin user registration form to include the membership no and I've added user_id to the members table.

Now how do I update the members table with the user_id?

Once the person has logged in using their "user_id" -- the rest of the application features will just be based on their "membership" data.

So, I think my relationships are:

- 1 user has 1 member
- 1 member has 1 user, 1 member has multiple clubs, 1 member has multiple positions, 1 member has multiple orders

I think the Plugin for Users is confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

How were the User model and Membership model associated in the first place?  You should have already had a Membership.user_id field.

If they're somehow connected already (I assume they are, since you said associations were working correctly), just write a quick MySQL query or repeating PHP script to run through and populate the Membership.user_id fields.  You'll only have to do it once now that you have the database and associations setup correctly.

Comment: Good question.  I think that is my downfall.  I'm not sure on how to go about associating the two models.  The "users" model comes from the Plugin.  The "members" model is mine (created using bake).  The Plugin works on its own and my portion works on it's own.  I can't seem to get them to work together.